How to customize the default spacing scale in Tailwind CSS?
I'm currently working on a project using Tailwind CSS and I find that the default spacing scale (like p-1, p-2, etc.) doesn't quite fit the design requirements of my project. I would like to customize this spacing scale to use different values.
I've read through the Tailwind CSS documentation, but I'm still a bit unclear on how to properly extend or override the default spacing scale.
My specific questions are:
How can I add new custom spacing values while still keeping the default ones available?
What is the best practice for overriding the default spacing scale entirely?
Are there any potential downsides to completely replacing the default scale with a custom one?
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '72': '18rem',
        '84': '21rem',
        '96': '24rem',
      }
    }
  }
}


This works for adding new values, but I’m unsure how to go about fully replacing the default scale, or if that's even advisable.
Any insights or best practices from experienced Tailwind CSS users would be greatly appreciated!

To add new custom spacing values while keeping the default ones available, you’ve already made the right start with your configuration:
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    spacing: {
      '1': '0.25rem',
      '2': '0.5rem',
      '3': '0.75rem',
      '4': '1rem',
      '5': '1.25rem',
      '6': '1.5rem',
      '7': '1.75rem',
      '8': '2rem',
      '9': '2.25rem',
      '10': '2.5rem',
      '12': '3rem',
      // Add custom values here
      '14': '3.5rem',
      '16': '4rem',
      // etc.
    }
  }
}

